# Not able to migrate One Note using Content Matrix

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, content-migration, onenote, metalogix

I am performing migration using Content Matrix for the SP Online Team site to Modern Team Site.

For one of the sites, while migrating the Onenote, I am getting a "Site Notebook feature is not activated" warning, and that notebook is skipped.

However, for other sites, it works fine without any issues.

I checked the site features and confirmed that the requested feature is activated still getting the above issue.

Anyone has faced a similar issue? Any workaround to migrate the OneNote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the manual approach for OneNote notebook migration if file author and editor metadata preservation is not a priority in the migration.

Try below manual steps to export and import the notebook:

Export steps:

- Go to source site.
- Open the source notebook file in OneNote desktop application.
- Go to File menu --> Export. Export whole notebook and save into local folder. It will download the file with `onepkg` extension.

Import steps:

- Launch OneNote desktop application.
- Go to File menu --> Open. Select this exported file to open in the app.
- "Unpack Notebook" dialog will appear. You can pass new notebook name and select your destination site path in the Path field.
- Click on Create button. It will take few seconds to process. After that newly migrated notebook will open in the app. Close this notebook.
- Go to the destination site in the browser and verify your migrated file.